# How to correctly loop a txt file using Get-Content CMDLET in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, arraylist, office365, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

Have created a script to export usermailbox statistics in office 365, the `script accepts a txt file` that has the list of specific users who i want to export that data from their accounts.

When i run the script, i get errors below:

```
Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'Identity'. Cannot convert the "System.Collections.ArrayList" value of type "System.Collections.ArrayList" to type
"Microsoft.Exchange.Configuration.Tasks.MailboxIdParameter".
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-Mailbox], ParameterBindin...mationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentTransformationError,Get-Mailbox
    + PSComputerName        : outlook.office365.com

The property '' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
At line:3 char:16
+     $mailbox = $_.
+                ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyAssignmentException

Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'Identity'. Cannot convert the "System.Collections.ArrayList" value of type "System.Collections.ArrayList" to type
"Microsoft.Exchange.Configuration.Tasks.GeneralMailboxOrMailUserIdParameter".
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-MailboxStatistics], ParameterBindin...mationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentTransformationError,Get-MailboxStatistics
    + PSComputerName        : outlook.office365.com

Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'Identity'. Cannot convert the "System.Collections.ArrayList" value of type "System.Collections.ArrayList" to type
"Microsoft.Exchange.Configuration.Tasks.GeneralMailboxOrMailUserIdParameter".
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-MailboxFolderStatistics], ParameterBindin...mationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentTransformationError,Get-MailboxFolderStatistics
    + PSComputerName        : outlook.office365.com
```

My script

```
$All = [collections.arraylist]@(get-content "C:\Users.txt")
$All | ForEach-Object {
    
    $mailbox = $_.
    $quota = Get-Mailbox -identity $mailbox | select ProhibitSendQuota, ProhibitSendReceiveQuota, RecoverableItemsQuota, ArchiveQuota, ArchiveWarningQuota
    $CurrentMailboxUsedSize = Get-MailboxStatistics -identity $mailbox | select TotalItemSize
    $recoverableitem = Get-MailboxFolderStatistics -identity $mailbox | ? {$_.Name -eq "Recoverable Items"}
    

    New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
   
        UserPrincipalName = $mailbox
        CurrentMailboxUsedSize = $CurrentMailboxUsedSize.TotalItemSize
        ProhibitSendQuota = $quota.ProhibitSendQuota
        MailboxTotalSize = $quota.ProhibitSendReceiveQuota
        CurrentRecoverableItemsSize = $recoverableitem.FolderAndSubfolderSize
        RecoverableItemsQuota = $quota.RecoverableItemsQuota        
        ArchiveMailboxQuota = $quota.ArchiveQuota
    ArchiveWarningQuota = $quota.ArchiveWarningQuota
   
    } 

} | Sort-Object 'UserPrincipalName', 'CurrentMailboxUsedSize', 'CurrentRecoverableItemsSize', 'ProhibitSendQuota', 'MailboxTotalSize', 'RecoverableItemsQuota', 'ArchiveMailboxQuota', 'ArchiveWarningQuota' | Export-CSV "C:\results.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

My text file
[image]

Where am i getting it wrong?

Comment: Not sure if this is intended but, the `.` after `$_` is a syntax error if you're not referring to a property of the object.

Comment: Why use an arraylist? Just go `Get-Content -Path "C:\Users.txt" | ForEach-Object{ ..}`

Comment: How will i reference the mailbox identity parameter, if i use that format. Thanks

Comment: Hi @Theo In my text file i got 2500 user addresses to loop each.

Comment: `$mailbox = $_; Get-Mailbox -Identity $mailbox` and 2500 addresses is a lot, but should not be a problem, just takes some time

Comment: Should i add `-ResultSize unlimited`  to look like this `$mailbox = $_; Get-Mailbox -Identity $mailbox -ResultSize unlimited` ?